# Python read data from Arduino using `HC-06`

Tags: python, arduino-uno

I would like to improve communication with Arduino and Python code. I mean that data would not come like b'...'....

I have py code:

```
import serial
s = serial.Serial("COM11",9600,timeout=2)
print("Conn")
s.write(b'FBLRLLRBFFBFFRLLLR')
while(True):
    data = s.read()
    print(str(data).rstrip())
    
s.close()
```

and arduino code:

```
void setup(){Serial.begin(9600);}
void loop(){
if(Serial.available()){
String data = Serial.readString();
Serial.prinln(data.length());}}
```

In result I want `28` but I got

```
b'2'
b'8'
b'\r'
b'\n'
```

How it would be possible?

Comment: have you tried ```Serial.readBytes```?

Comment: I made that python read line (`readline()`) and after that decode data with `decode("utf-8")`, now my code works as I wanted.